# How to change points to commas on axes in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, localization, locale

I added to my code

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE")

plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

and it does not work `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

I tested wheater I have `de_DE` listed in `locale -a` and I have not:

```
cs_CZ.utf8
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
id_ID.utf8
POSIX
```

Is here a default comma in some of them too? I thought that CZ, but not, there are still points. So I tried to install de_DE

```
cd /usr/share/locales
./install-language-pack de_DE
```

However, the result was

```
sed: dočasný soubor /etc/sed8Oob4Q nelze otevřít: Operace zamítnuta
```

that means the operation was 
rejected.

Writing instead of `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')` `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')` helped not as well.

I tried to ran in terminal

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Sould I have chosen de_DE like default language althrough I use another language?

Then I used `export LC_ALL=C` and nothing happend. Have you got another ideas to set in matplotlib commas instead of point on axes? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You code is incorrect you call `plt.rcParams` before loading matplotlib.

This code works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True
import locale

print(locale.getlocale()) # default locale, have to be None 
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "de") # 'de' for Win or 'de_DE' for linux/mac
print(locale.getlocale()) # test locale after setup
fig, axis = plt.subplots(2, 2)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and please how to install de_DE? In my question is an error that I got when I tried it.

Comment: Read this link: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu It may be help you.